# Ajax won't display linked dropdown list second list options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Started to learn scripting. But can't figure out, how to debug my problem. Got 2 linked drop down lists. Regions -> Countries. But, when I choose region that I want, in country dropdown, dosn't show any options.

My backend code.

```
public function selectCountry(){
    try
    {
        if(!empty($_POST["region"])) {

            $region=$_GET['region'];
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY country WHERE region_id='$region'");

            $stmt->execute();

            foreach($stmt as $country) { 
                echo "<option value='" . $country['country'] ."'>"  . $country['country'] . "</option>";        
            }

        return $stmt;   
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }   
}
```

And front script.

```
<script>
function getCountry(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../System/class.map.php",
    data:'region='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#country").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML side:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="region">Region</label>
<div class="controls">
<select name="region" id="region" class="form-control" onChange="getCountry(this.value); "> <option value=''>Select Region<?php $map->selectRegion(); ?></option></select>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label>
<div class="controls">
<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control"> <option value=''>Select Country<?php $map->selectCountry(); ?></option></select>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of potential things here that could be a problem. First off, are you getting any data back from the PHP?

Comment: Like from database? If i take out all this linked script, then it display all countries, no matter what region.

Comment: Yes...are you sure the database (via your PHP) is actually returning anything?

Comment: Yes. Becouse, without this script. Database return all countries. If I understood you right.

Comment: And there have to be errors somewhere because I don't see where you define `val`

Comment: onChange="getCountry(this.value); Here? :? Not really sure, I'm real begginer, who is trying to learn by myself.